# Updating a table using gridview stored procedure, does not update my table

Tags: sql, asp.net, gridview

So when i click on edit and then type in a new value, and click update.. the value just goes back to what it originally was, does anybody know where i am going wrong on my code.. my stored procedure is fine but i suspect i am missing something on my code.. when i step through my code, it just picks up the value that is in the table and then sends it to my stored procedure... here is the code

```
 protected void GridView1_OnRowEditing(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
        {

            GridView1.EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex;
            GridView1.DataBind();
        }



        protected void GridView1_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
        {
            // Assign Target property Value

            TextBox tb = (TextBox) GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("TargetTextBox"); //finds the target column
            Target = int.Parse((tb.Text));
            int id = int.Parse(GridView1.DataKeys[e.RowIndex].Value.ToString());
            using (DataManager dmgr = new DataManager())
            {
                dmgr.Connect("PRODUCTION");

                dmgr.PackingShiftTargetUpdate(id, Target);

                dmgr.Disconnect();
            }

            GridView1.EditIndex = -1;
            GridView1.DataBind();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please let us have a look at your ado.net code?

Answer (score 0):

A couple things to check. When running the edit through the web app verify that the change is being made in your sql table. If not then there is an issue with the way your webapp calls the stored proc, if so and the web app is still displaying the old data then it is related to the way you are initializing your GridView1 on page load or on Postback. If you are not using a PostBackTrigger you will need either an AsyncPostBackTrigger (uses AJAX) or a C# !IsPostBack, and link your Gridview1 to it

```
private void Page_Load()
{
if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        // call GridView1 here         
    }
}
```

If you could edit your question with your Page_Load() function snippet as well that would be helpful